# How about a function return a pointer that points to heap-allocated object

Tags: c

I'm reading the book "C interfaces and implementations"，here is a piece of code that I think there is something wrong:

```
    void* stack_pop(Stack stack) {
          assert(stack->count > 0);
          struct Elem* elem = stack->head;
          stack->head = elem->next;
          stack->count--;
          void* x = elem->data;
          free(elem);
          return x;
}
```

Here is the definition of struct stack:

```
typedef struct Stack {
       int count;
       struct Elem {
              void* data;
              struct Elem* next;
       } *head;
} Stack;
```

The function `stack_pop` return a pointer,but where it points to?  Will this cause an undefined behavior because of `free(elem)`?

Comment: Why are you defining a struct inside of another struct? That's nuts. Elem needs to be fully defined before being added as a variable type in Stack.

Comment: It returns a reference to the former head's payload.

Comment: I see that. Why can't he *define* it first, and then *use* it with `struct Elem head;` inside the definition of Stack?

Comment: stack->head = elem->next;   head is a structure variable elem is a pointer. Wrong assignment Structure should be typedef struct Stack {
       int count;
       struct Elem {
              void* data;
              struct Elem* next;
       } *head;
} Stack;

Comment: @JonahNelson sorry, I miss the pointer of head

Comment: @sunmoon you are right, I miss the pointer,sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stack_pop()` returns a reference to the data carried by the former head of the stack, the head being pop off the stack by this call to `stack_pop()`.

As `data` is defined to be a pointer `(void *)` this operation **copies** its value to `x`:

```
void * x = elem->data;
```

so freeing `elem` (and its member `data` with it) **afterwards** is perfectly alright. Note, that only the **reference** (`data`) to the payload it `free()`ed, not the referred payload itself (what `data` pointed to).

Also please note that `stack_pop()` **misses to check whether `head` is `NULL`**. Do not call it after the last element had been popped off the stack.

Comment: free(elem) only freed tow pointers（actually two address）,but the object that pointer pointer to is still there, am I right?

Comment: @wwwjieo0: Yes, you are.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that probably you are using `void*` in the element to allow any type of data to be stored in this stack. So, your "`pointer`" might not necessarily be a pointer (you may have to cast the return of `stack_pop()`).

Additionally, when you free a pointer, you are only freeing that piece of allocated memory, regardless of the other pointers that memory may contain in its struct. That is, when you `free()` a pointer, free is not "recursive", it will not `free()` the memory that `void* data` inside Elem points to.

Comment: free is not "recursive". this is the reason, Thank you